# My textchanged listener is launching a loop when i hit the first row of my listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, listener, android-edittext, textchanged

I have a listview with 2 buttons, 1 textview and one edittext, the textview show the name of the products, the two buttons (- & +) increase or decrease the quantity wich is in my edittext.

Everything is working just fine for the 3 last rows (out of 4), it shows me the position on my list, the name of the product, the quantity, the price, everything i need. But as soon as i hit any of the button from the first row it's going for 9 lap loop.. My Toasts are showing a new position at each toast with the appropriate info except the quantity which stick to the one of the first row.

Here is the getView of my custom adapter which extends BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_product, null);
    }

    final int pos = position;
    Button btnProdChoiMinus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProdChoiMinus);
    TextView tvProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProduct);
    Button btnProdChoiPlus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProdChoiPlus);
    final EditText etQuantity = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.etQuantite);

    final Produit p= data.get(position);

    btnProdChoiMinus.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.lblMinus));
    tvProduit.setText(p.getNom());
    btnProdChoiPlus.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.lblPlus));
```

In the same method I have my 2 button listerners:

```
btnProdChoiMinus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (etQuantity.getText().toString().length() != 0){
                quantite = Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) - 1;
                if (quantite > 0){
                    etQuantity.setText("" + quantite);
                }else{
                    etQuantity.setText("");
                }

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.lblErrQuantity_fr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    btnProdChoiPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (etQuantity.getText().toString().length() != 0){
                quantite = Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) + 1;
                etQuantity.setText("" + quantite);

            }else{
                etQuantity.setText("1");
            }
        }
    });
```

And finaly still in the same method, my textchanged lister which is causing this issue:

```
etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (etQuantity.getText().toString().length() != 0){

                    quantite = Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString());

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Position: " + pos + " Produit: " + p.getNom() + " id: " + p.getId() + " Prix: " + p.getPrix() + " Quantité: " + quantite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //((NewOrderActivity)activity).updateOrderedProducts(p.getId(), p.getNom(), p.getPrix(), quantite);
                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
```

I already tried to switch from afterTextChanged to onTextChanged but it didn't help.

Your help is very much appreciated ;)

Regards,

Seb

Answer (score 0):

This happens because *etQuantity.addTextChangedListener* every time add another one listener to your *etQuantity* widget.

So when View in *ListView* is reused you just add yet another listener to *etQuantity* (NOT replace old one), and all of this listeners will fire. Try to use for example [etQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29) and update quantity when *etQuantity* loose focus (also you should add *((NewOrderActivity)activity).updateOrderedProducts(p.getId(), p.getNom(), p.getPrix(), quantite);* to *onClick* listeners of your buttons) instead of *etQuantity.addTextChangedListener*

Or, you could save your listener in holder and call *etQuantity.addTextChangedListener* only once, when you create holder